# Analytical solution of linear SDE driven by fractional Brownian motion without drift

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the SDE driven by the fractional Brownian motion with Hurst parameter $H \in (0.5, 1)$
$$\mathrm{d}Y_t = aY_t\mathrm{d}B^H_t + bY_t\mathrm{d}t, \quad Y_0 = \xi$$
Then they state in [this paper](http://www.minet.uni-jena.de/fakultaet/mgeo/publicat/pdffiles/iwrtff1_ptrf98.pdf) on page 22 of the pdf that this has as unique solution
$$Y_t = \xi\exp(aB^H_t + bt)$$
I am interested in the case that there is no drift term ($b\equiv0$), see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591378/how-to-empirically-verify-convergence-results-with-stochastic-differential-equat) I posted today.

The paper states that this solution follows directly from the change of variables formula given in $(31)$:
\begin{equation*}
F(f(y)) - F(f(a)) = \int_a^y F'(f(t))\mathrm{d}f(t)
\end{equation*}
I take that it should be $f(t) = B^H_t$, but then I have no clue how they get to the result mentioned above.

I know it's probably trivial, but it has been bugging for far too long.

Any help, complete solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: $F(z) := \xi e^z$ and $f(t) := a B_t^H + bt$, then $df(t) = a dB_t^H+b dt$ and you just have to plug it into (31)... or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @saz it's most likely that I am missing something... I tried filling in your functions, but to no avail. The lhs in (31) is the solution $\xi \exp(aB^H_t + bt)$, but I can't reduce the rhs to $Y_t$. It would be nice if you could explain it like I am a five year old with a half decent maths education. Apperantly I need that at the moment.